# AWS S3 access from RDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working a Cloud project, I created an RDP using AWS and I installed my software there. I want to know if I can access my S3 bucket folder from this RDP.

I looked on the web for a solution but I didn't find one, I only found a [solution via FTP server](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/how-to-connect-to-amazon-s3-f2665.html) and it worked but I didn't want this solution.

Comment: Based on your comment, below, you have not actually asked about what you are trying to do -- which is *mount* the bucket and access it from Windows Explorer.  That *might* be possible, using a third party utility, but it is not really how S3 is designed to be used -- S3 is not a filesystem.  Questions asking for tool recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but i tried for ftp solution and loocking on the internet but no real result... so i didn't find better way for my problem, Stackoverflow is the best, can you please help me to resolve my issue?? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can access it from the RDP instance just like from any other machine.

Easiest/best way is to assign an IAM role to the instance, and make sure that that IAM role has the rights it needs to access the bucket - this keeps you from having to store your credentials anywhere in your code or on the machine.

Once the permissions are set properly, you can access the S3 bucket via your application and/or the CLI (or even the aws console if you are using a windows ec2 instance that has a gui).

Comment: can you please explain to me step by step or if there is tutorial, i just want to  see my S3 as a folder in my amazon RDP
thanks :)